# How to convert a TimeStamp in a List<String> to String?

Tags: java, string, list, timestamp

It's my first post,

I have a problem i have a sql.Timestamp in my List and i want to do set the value
of a the timestamp in a String

```
            setModificationDate(listDossier.get(12));
```

The problem is when i try it i have an

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.lang.String

I tried to do an setModificationDate(listDossier.get(12).toString()); but i didnt't work too.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgFN4.png

setModificationDate is just an String.

Thanks for the help

Comment: It seems premature to be doing database work without having first learned about basic classes like [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: How can a `List<String>` contains a `Timestamp`?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. And no matter what, avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class that @VGR mentioned. It’s notoriously troublesome and has long gone out of any reasonable use whatsoever. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: And in what context do you want to set the timestamp as string? A timestamp should always be kept as a date-time object such as `Instant`. Only when you need to give string output, convert to string. That doesn’t seem to be the need right here?

Comment: Hello thx for anwser
I develop an Api rest in spring boot, i have a JDBCquerry who give me in output a List<Map<String,Object> , i convert it in List<String> that why i have still have Timestamp in my List<String>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DateFormatter. Example:

```java
String pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSS"; 
String timestampAsString = "Nov 12, 2018 13:02:56.12345678"; 
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern); 
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(formatter.parse(timestampAsString));
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. I think the opposite conversion was called for, from `Timestamp` to `String`.

Comment: yes, correct. thanks @OleV.V.